# drawing a specific kind of outline

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, hexagonal-tiles

Not sure if this possible in three.js, but I'd like to draw similar outline as you can see on the picture below.

[image]

Currently I'm using LineSegments,

[image]

which is good, but I like the one used in "Sid Meier's Starships" better. Although I'm not really sure how do I achieve this gradient , semi-transparent effect on a border.